# cURL response different than web response

Tags: php, html, curl, load, php-curl

I Want to get all page contents that i have them urls

i wrote the following php code for get content of https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans

```
 function curl_file_get_content($url){
    $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
            CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>$agent,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>5,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>0,
            CURLOPT_SSLVERSION=>3,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>0,
        ]);
    $page=curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) return $page;
    else return false;
}
if($content=curl_file_get_content("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans")){
    echo $content;
}else{
    echo "the Website is DOWN" ;
}
```

output is the following code

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3fY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot);
}
```

if you look the url [https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans) you will notice content of this page and output of my code is deffrent and my code output is a part off that page

but this code is work correctly for get content of localhost files

whats the problem? 
can i get this page full contents?

Answer (score 3):

It's the user agent you've used, when I set it to `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36` it seemed to return the full content like it should.

```
function fetch($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        ]);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return array($code, $page);
}

list ($code, response) = fetch('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans');

if ($code == 200) {
    echo $response;
} else {
    echo 'Unable to fetch content: ' . $code;
    echo 'Response: ' . $response;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! - why google does not return the full contents for `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)` and return full contents for  `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36` What is my agent problem? does you know ?